# Chromium nightly build location

Tags: chromium, automated-builds

Until recently (last month I would say), you could find the Chromium nightly builds at this address:

> http://build.chromium.org/f/chromium/snapshots/

However, it looks like there is nothing there anymore.

Where are Chromium nightly builds now?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[The answer you seek is here](http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-continuous/index.html). You can also find more links on the [build page](http://chromium-build-master.appspot.com/p/chromium/console)

Comment: In fact, if you go to the parent of the old one above, then to *Continuous*, you can find a [`README`](http://build.chromium.org/f/chromium/continuous/README.txt) that indicates the new location. `;-)`

Answer (score 1):

You can also install the Chrome Canary for [Windows](https://tools.google.com/dlpage/chromesxs?platform=win) and [Mac](https://tools.google.com/dlpage/chromesxs?platform=mac). It's a channel that automatically updates nightly and runs in its own profile.

Comment: This is an even better answer. Easier to install and automatically updates.

Answer (score 1):

In general, using the Canary build is a better idea than using one of the build directly from Google Storage.

That said, if you do want to use whatever the absolute latest build it, you can follow the instructions on the Chromium [getting involved](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/getting-involved/dev-channel#TOC-How-do-I-choose-which-channel-to-use-) page.

The second link in qweet's answer is outdated. If you want to view the Chromium continuous build waterfall, please visit [build.chromium.org](http://build.chromium.org).